# Probability of matches being random

Tags: probability, random-generation

We have a set of 576 samples that have been assayed to obtain some omics information (genomic/epigenomic). The 576 samples are mostly from unique individuals, but we have some samples for which the same individual has been done in replicates (sometimes 10-20 times), giving a total of about 470 unique individuals.

The individuals have two recorded ethnicities: A or B. The omics data gives us an estimate in a percentage of their genome that is classed within two reference populations: C for individuals we expect as A and D for individuals we expect as B.

Given that all but 10 samples are classed as being high C percentage and zero D percentage (70% approx), or high D percentage and zero C percentage (remaining 30%), what is the probability that there has been a sample swap in the wet lab and we still see almost perfect A<->C and B<->D concordance?

I naively would think that one would give a probability of 0.5 of a sample being A or B, and ignoring the 10% samples that are not pure C or D, the probability of having sample swaps in the lab but still correctly classing White/Asian as CEU/GUJ would be `0.5^num_samples`.

Is that correct?